# Is it possible to automate the execution of a Python script using Microsoft Flow?

Tags: python, automation, power-automate

I want to execute a snippet of python code based on some trigger using Microsoft-Flow. Is there a way to do this?

Basically I am exploring on Powerapps and Microsoft-Flow. I have data in powerapp, I can do basic operations there. But, I want to execute a python script whenever a user press button in the powerapp and display the result on powerapp again.

Comment: You will need to provide a bit more details like: Where is your python code located? What is the input and output of your trigger and what do you want to do within the trigger? etc

Comment: @ChrisChen I have edited my question in order to provide more details on what I am trying to do. As of now, I have code in my local, I am not sure where should I store it. I tried Azure ML but I guess there is no connector for Azure ML and PowerApp also.

Comment: Have you consider setting up OpenAPI connector? https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/register-custom-api/

Answer (score 5):

In theory you can do with Azure Functions.  The steps you need are the following:

1. [Create an Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview)
2. [Create the API definition using Python as the language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-openapi-definition)
3. [Export the definition to PowerApps/Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/app-service-export-api-to-powerapps-and-flow)
4. [Add the function to your app as a data source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-powerapps-scenario) OR
5. [Add the function to Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-flow-scenario)

It is still a little bit experimental, but you should be able to make it work.

Comment: Hi. Last 2 links are broken.