# Not able to create a python function in azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm not able to create the azure function in python which can be used to run python script on PowerApps.

I've tried it on command prompt and also on a visual studio in the app got created but I was not able to deploy it.

[Is it possible to automate the execution of a Python script using Microsoft Flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718344/is-it-possible-to-automate-the-execution-of-a-python-script-using-microsoft-flow)
I'm using this link to create the azure function

```
(.env) C:\Users\PAhire2\MyFunctionProj>az functionapp create --resource-group myResourceGroup --os-type Windows --consumption-plan-location westeurope --runtime python --name NewApp --storage-account 1234store
usage error: Currently supported runtimes (--runtime) in windows function apps are: dotnet, node, java, powershell.
```

This is the error message I'm getting

Answer (score 2):

You get this error cause the python function only could be created on the Linux OS on Azure, so just change your os-type to Linux, it will be success.

```
az functionapp create --resource-group mygroup --os-type Linux --consumption-plan-location westeurope --runtime python --name pythonfunctiontest --storage-account mystorageaccount
```

I test with Azure Cloud Shell and it works. Hope this could help you. Also you could refer to the tutorial:[Create a function app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python#create-a-function-app-in-azure).

[image]